# Using SPARQL to find the graphs in triple-store

Tags: sparql, graphdb, named-graphs

I've been using the following SPARQL query to find the graphs in a triple-store:

```
select distinct ?g where { graph ?g {?s ?p ?o} }
```

This seems inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Comment: That's the standard way. Anything else might be some triple store dependent service, but I don't think there is any other way with SPARQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the SPARQL query to get the name of all graphs existsing in my fuseki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274562/what-is-the-sparql-query-to-get-the-name-of-all-graphs-existsing-in-my-fuseki)

Comment: @JeenBroekstra: Yes. Not necessarily a duplicate, but definitely related. I didn't see that post until you pointed it out.

Comment: Do you actually have performance issues?

Answer (score 2):

The form:

```
SELECT * { GRAPH ?g {} }
```

will give you all the graph names, no duplicates.

Comment: I'm using the free version of GraphDB, version 8.0. This doesn't work.

Comment: Suggest you report it GraphDB. It is legal SPARQL 1.1.  See 3rd case of eval of "graph" https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_evalGraph .