# How to recover the URI of all named graphs with SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, triplestore, named-graphs

How to recover the URI of all named graphs with SPARQL?
And how can I recover every quad (subject predicate object graph) of my triplestore with SPARQL?

Comment: Well, do you really mean "recover"? Or did you mean "discover"? `select disitnct ?g {graph ?g {?s ?p ?o}}` should return all graphs. All quads is almost the same: `select ?s ?p ?o ?g {graph ?g {?s ?p ?o}}`

Comment: AKSW, with your query, your are missing the empty graphs.

Comment: And there is a typo as well...thanks. This query then maybe: `select ?g {graph ?g {}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the SPARQL query to get the name of all graphs existing in my triplestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274562/what-is-the-sparql-query-to-get-the-name-of-all-graphs-existing-in-my-triplestor)

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Stores don't necessarily store empty graphs and the specs explicitly allow for this so even if you modify the query to `select distinct ?g { graph ?g { } }` it doesn't guarantee to return empty graphs