# Sparql-List of Datasets

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm doing a small task on SPARQL.

I don't have a query but I just want to know is there a way to write a SPARQL query to : 'Get the list of Dataset' ?

I'm using DBpedia Endpoint.

Comment: What do you mean by "dataset". DBPedia is a dataset.. https://wiki.dbpedia.org/develop/datasets

Comment: There is no concept of dataset in SAPRQL language. The only thing that might be related is the concept of `graphs`. how to query for all graphs in a triple store was answered already, just use the search function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the SPARQL query to get the name of all graphs existing in my triplestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274562/what-is-the-sparql-query-to-get-the-name-of-all-graphs-existing-in-my-triplestor)

Comment: Ok. I was searching this 
http://void.rkbexplorer.com/sparql/. 
This will allow me to list the dataset for any endpoint.

Comment: But anyways thanks for letting me know guys

Comment: Some endpoints store and make available voiD data; many (I daresay, most) do not. The query you found at <http://void.rkbexplorer.com/sparql/> will not let you list the dataset for "any endpoint" -- only for those which have stored and made that data queryable.

Answer (score 0):

RKBexplorer is a mirror of some LOD datasets, it's partial and I don't know whether it's still maintained. You can get bigger lists of LOD datasets eg at:

- https://lod-cloud.net/
- http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql/
- http://lod-a-lot.lod.labs.vu.nl/ (currently down)